# Can't query/order on built-in rally fields "could not read all instances of class com.f4tech.slm.domain.Artifact"

Tags: c#, rally

I'm using v2.0 of the API via the C# dll.  **But this problem also happens when I pass a Query String to the v2.0 API** via https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/

I'm querying at the Artifact level because I need both Defects and Stories.  I tried to see what kind of query string the Rally front end is using, and it passes custom fields and built-in fields to the artifact query.  I am doing the same thing, but am not finding any luck getting it to work.

I need to be able to filter out the released items from my query.  Furthermore, I also need to sort by the custom c_ReleaseType field as well as the built-in DragAndDropRank field.  I'm guessing this is a problem because those built-in fields are not actually on the Artifact object, but why would the custom fields work?  They're not on the Artifact object either.  It might just be a problem I'm not able to guess at hidden in the API.  If I can query these objects based on custom fields, I would expect the ability would exist to query them by built-in fields as well, even if those fields don't exist on the Ancestor object.

For the sake of the example, I am leaving out a bunch of the setup code... and only leaving in the code that causes the issues.

```
var request = new Request("Artifact");
request.Order = "DragAndDropRank";  
//"Could not read: could not read all instances of class com.f4tech.slm.domain.Artifact"
```

**When I comment the Order by DragAndDropRank line, it works.**

---

```
var request = new Request("Artifact");
request.Query = (new Query("c_SomeCustomField", Query.Operator.Equals, "somevalue").
            And(new Query("Release", Query.Operator.Equals, "null"))); 
//"Could not read: could not read all instances of class com.f4tech.slm.domain.Artifact"
```

**When I take the Release part out of the query, it works.**

---

```
var request = new Request("Artifact");
request.Query = (((new Query("TypeDefOid", Query.Operator.Equals, "someID"). 
            And(new Query("c_SomeCustomField", Query.Operator.Equals, "somevalue"))).
            And(new Query("DirectChildrenCount", Query.Operator.Equals, "0")))); 
//"Could not read: could not read all instances of class com.f4tech.slm.domain.Artifact"
```

**When I take the DirectChildrenCount part out of the query, it works.**

---

Here's an example of the problem demonstrated by an API call.

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/artifact?query=(c_KanbanState%20%3D%20%22Backlog%22)&order=DragAndDropRank&start=1&pagesize=20

**When I remove the Order by DragAndDropRank querystring, it works.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most of your trouble is due to the fact that in order to use the Artifact endpoint you need to specify a types parameter so it knows which artifact sub classes to include.

Simply adding that to your example WSAPI query above causes it to return successfully:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/artifact?query=(c_KanbanState = "Backlog")&order=DragAndDropRank&start=1&pagesize=20&types=hierarchicalrequirement,defect
```

However I'm not tally sure if the C# API allows you to encode additional custom parameters onto the request...

Comment: That does in fact fix the problem from the API.  I will check it out via the C# DLL.  Hopefully it's an easy fix if it's not already implemented.

Comment: You will probably just need to add an AddParameter method or expose the Parameters dictionary on Request.  This is necessary to solve the other open pull request around supporting rankTo and rankAbove/Below parameters anyway and would be a good addition...

Comment: I created a pull request. https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/pull/18

Answer (score 1):

Your question already contains the answer.

UserStory (HierarchicalRequirement in WS API) and Defect inherit some of their fields from Artifact, e.g. FormattedID, Name, Description, LastUpdateDate, etc. You may use those fields in the context of Artifact type.

The fields that you are trying to access on Artifact object do not exist on it. They exist on a child level, e.g. DragAndDropRank, Release, Iteration. It is not possible to use those fields in the context of Artifact type.

Parent objects don't have access to attributes specific to child object.
Artifact is an abstract type.

If you need to filter by Release, you need to make two separate requests - one for stories, the other for defects.

Comment: Your answer doesn't clarify why I cannot query/sort on built-in fields which are not on the Artifact level (Release, DragAndDropRank)  but I can query/sort on custom fields (c_SomeCustomField) which are also not on the Artifact level.

Comment: child object can have access to a field inherited from a parent, but an a parent does not have access to a field specific to a child. (in this case Artifact is also abstract)

Comment: Let me reword it as a question.  Why can I query/sort on custom fields (c_SomeCustomField) which are not on the Artifact level but I cannot query/sort on built-in fields which are also not on the Artifact level (Release, DragAndDropRank)?

Comment: @agibson Hmm..I cannot replicate that in WS API. See screenshots from https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/ Can you replicate it in WS API?

Comment: Yes, I can duplicate this in the API. I will post more details in my original post.  In your test, you're querying a custom field but according to their API docs, you have to query a custom field with "c_" prepended.  I'm 100% certain if you query c_KanbanState on the Artifact object, you will get your the stories you would expect as if you were querying HierarchicalRequirement.  See the section called "Custom Field Names".

Comment: yes, you are correct about custom fields on Artifacts - this time I got results back without using "c_".  "c_" can be omitted unless there is a name clash with a built-in field. You're right: while Artifact can't be queried in WS API  by Release or other built-in attributes it can be queried by a custom field.